# webpack 4/vue.js example for internet explorer 11 with several entry points

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webpack, vue.js

This is my umpteenth internet explorer with webpack déjà vu. I'm almost done with with my project, close to deploy, and ie 11 f$&#s up everything.

I dont't know why. I thought I had everything covered with babel-polyfill and the last two versions. But that would have been too easy.

I am getting:

The object doesn't support the property or method "includes".
(Original message in German: Das Objekt unterstützt die Eigenschaft oder Methode "includes" nicht)

And it's complaining about this piece of code:

/******/ if (!me.children.includes(request)) me.children.push(request);

So obviously **Array.prototype.includes** is not being polyfilled.

The webpack config for vue js client side rendering basically looking like this:

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: {
    app1: ['babel-polyfill', 'picturefill', './src/entry-client1.js'],
    app2: ['babel-polyfill', 'picturefill', './src/entry-client1.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public/dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist
  }
  /* some other stuff */
}
```

I am using Webpack version 4.1 and Vue version 2.5.15. And it's IE11.

Maybe someone can simply point me to a an config example that actually works with IE11. I don't even care asking about any former IE versions anymore.

Comment: Do you have the babel-polyfill package under dependencies installed (not devDependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to install (`npm i --save core-js` or `yarn add core-js`) and then to add at the top of your entry point of your project

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support